# Apache2 Mod rewrite page not found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm sorry that I'm not exactly sure how to phrase the question in a single sentence.

Basically, mod rewrite is working for our traq pages (code block 1 below), but not for our wordpress pages (code block 2 below). For some reason, if we implement the automatically generated Wordpress .htaccess file, the page comes up with Apache's "page not found" error (which means that it's never hitting Wordpress's index page at all).

Traq:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Wordpress:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
<IfModule>
```

We tried commenting out a few of the various lines in the Wordpress file, and altering various lines as we thought one thing or another might have been causing the issue. In the end, none of our changes got anything to display except 404.

Comment: Try removing the two `.IfModule...` lines. (PS the last `<IfModule>` should have been `</IfModule>`)

Comment: I copied that last line wrong. We attempted commenting out those lines, to no avail, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue.
Our server is set up pretty much as Ubuntu from distro, and by default the apache package is configured to allow overwrite with htaccess / mod-rewrite, but not to allow any rewrite rules. We had to add the rules we wanted to allow to the apache config.